# Cambio de frame en javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

¿Cómo puedo cambiar de un *frame* a otro cerrando el primer *frame* en *javaFX*?

Tengo el siguiente código, pero no funciona, no me abre las otras ventanas:

Clase PruebaVentanas:

```
package pruebaventanas;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PruebaVentanas extends Application {

    private Stage stagePrincipal;
    private AnchorPane rootPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stagePrincipal) throws Exception {
        this.stagePrincipal = stagePrincipal;
        mostrarVentanaPrincipal();

    }

    /*
     * cargamos la ventana principal
     */
    public void mostrarVentanaPrincipal() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(PruebaVentanas.class.getResource("VentanaPrincipal.fxml"));
            rootPane=(AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);
            stagePrincipal.setTitle(".: TEAM :.");
            stagePrincipal.setScene(scene);
            VentanaPrincipalController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setProgramaPrincipal(this);
            stagePrincipal.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void mostrarVentanaSecundaria() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(PruebaVentanas.class.getResource("cMenuTutor.fxml"));
            AnchorPane ventanaDos = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage ventana2 = new Stage();
            ventana2.setTitle("Bienvenido Tutor");
            ventana2.initOwner(stagePrincipal);
            Scene scene = new Scene(ventanaDos);
            ventana2.setScene(scene);
            cMenuTutorController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setStagePrincipal(ventana2);
            ventana2.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    public void mostrarPerfilTutor() {
        try {
           // System.out.println("holla");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(PruebaVentanas.class.getResource("cPerfilTutor.fxml"));
          // System.out.println("jjja");
            AnchorPane ventanaTres = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage ventana3 = new Stage();
            ventana3.setTitle("Bienvenido Tutor");
            ventana3.initOwner(stagePrincipal);
            Scene scene3 = new Scene(ventanaTres);
            ventana3.setScene(scene3);
            cPerfilTutorController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setStagePrincipal(ventana3);
            ventana3.show();
            /**FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(PruebaVentanas.class.getResource("VentanaPrincipal.fxml"));
            rootPane=(AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);
            stagePrincipal.setTitle(".: TEAM :.");
            stagePrincipal.setScene(scene);
            VentanaPrincipalController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setProgramaPrincipal(this);
            stagePrincipal.show();*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void mostrarMenuAdministrador() {
        try {
            System.out.println("holla");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(PruebaVentanas.class.getResource("cMenuAdministrador.fxml"));
            System.out.println("jjja");
            AnchorPane ventanaCuatro = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage ventana4 = new Stage();
            ventana4.setTitle("Bienvenido Administrador");
            ventana4.initOwner(stagePrincipal);
            Scene scene4 = new Scene(ventanaCuatro);
            ventana4.setScene(scene4);
            cMenuAdministradorController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setStagePrincipal(ventana4);
            ventana4.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void mostrarPerfilAdministrador() {
        try {
           // System.out.println("holla");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(PruebaVentanas.class.getResource("cPerfilAdministrador.fxml"));
          // System.out.println("jjja");
            AnchorPane ventanaCinco = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage ventana5 = new Stage();
            ventana5.setTitle("Bienvenido Administrador");
            ventana5.initOwner(stagePrincipal);
            Scene scene5 = new Scene(ventanaCinco);
            ventana5.setScene(scene5);
            cPerfilAdministradorController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setStagePrincipal(ventana5);
            ventana5.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="350" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="pruebaventanas.VentanaPrincipalController">
    <children>
        <Label layoutX="100" layoutY="20" minWidth="120" minHeight="25" fx:id="label" text="HyperGerät Presenta"  />
        <Label layoutX="135" layoutY="45" minWidth="120" minHeight="25" fx:id="labelt" text=" TEAM"  />
        <TextField layoutX="120" layoutY="120" minWidth="100" minHeight="25" fx:id="usuario"    />
        <TextField layoutX="120" layoutY="160" minWidth="100" minHeight="25" fx:id="contrasena"    />
        <Label layoutX="50" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label2" text="Usuario"/>
        <Label layoutX="50" layoutY="160" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label3" text="Contraseña"/>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="235" text="Abrir Ventana" onAction="#ventanaNew" fx:id="button" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Clase VentanaPrincipalController:

```
package pruebaventanas;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class VentanaPrincipalController implements Initializable {

    private PruebaVentanas ProgramaPrincipal;

    @FXML
    private void ventanaNew(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Entra boton");
        validaUsuario();
        ProgramaPrincipal.mostrarMenuAdministrador();

    }

    public void setProgramaPrincipal(PruebaVentanas ProgramaPrincipal) {
        this.ProgramaPrincipal = ProgramaPrincipal;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    private void validaUsuario(){

    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="350" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="pruebaventanas.cMenuTutorController">
<children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="120" text="Mi Perfil" onAction="#perfilTutor" fx:id="perfil" />
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="160" text="Actividades" onAction="#salirVentana" fx:id="actividades" />
        <Button layoutX="200" layoutY="280" text="Cerrar  Sesion" onAction="#salirVentana" fx:id="cerrarSesion" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Clase cMenuTutorController:

```
package pruebaventanas;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class cMenuTutorController implements Initializable {
    private Stage stagePrincipal;
    private PruebaVentanas prueba = new PruebaVentanas();

    public void setStagePrincipal(Stage stagePrincipal) {
        this.stagePrincipal = stagePrincipal;
    }

    @FXML
    private void salirVentana(ActionEvent event) {
        stagePrincipal.close();
    }

    @FXML
    private void perfilTutor(ActionEvent event) {
        try{
            System.out.println("Cambia Algo");
            prueba.mostrarPerfilTutor();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            String xD = e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(xD);
        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void menuTutorAdmin(ActionEvent event) {
        try{
            System.out.println("Cambia Algo");
            prueba.mostrarPerfilTutor();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            String xD = e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(xD);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="pruebaventanas.cPerfilAdministradorController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@ventanados.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
            <Button layoutX="25" layoutY="125" fx:id="consultar"   text="Consultar mi Informacion"  />
            <Button layoutX="25" layoutY="200" fx:id="modifica" text="Modificar Informacion"  />
            <Button layoutX="25" layoutY="300" fx:id="atras" text="⬅"  />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Clase cPerfilAdministradorController:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pruebaventanas;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Otoniel Aguirre
 */
public class cPerfilAdministradorController implements Initializable {

    private Stage stagePrincipal;

    public void setStagePrincipal(Stage stagePrincipal) {
        this.stagePrincipal = stagePrincipal;
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="pruebaventanas.cPerfilTutorController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@ventanados.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
            <Button layoutX="25" layoutY="125" fx:id="consulta"   text="Consultar mi Informacion"  />
            <Button layoutX="25" layoutY="200" fx:id="modificar" text="Modificar Informacion"  />
            <Button layoutX="25" layoutY="300" fx:id="atras" text="⬅"  />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Clase cPerfilTutorController:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Otoniel Aguirre
 */
public class cPerfilTutorController implements Initializable {
    private Stage stagePrincipal;

    public void setStagePrincipal(Stage stagePrincipal) {
        this.stagePrincipal = stagePrincipal;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

El problema es que no me abre la siguiente ventana, ni me muestra nada.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba a hacerlo de esta manera,por ejemplo en la función mostrarMenuAdministrador que salta a la siguiente ventana después de clickar el botón abrir ventana.

```
public void mostrarMenuAdministrador(Event event) {
    try {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("cMenuTutor.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        appStage.setScene(scene);
        appStage.toFront();
        appStage.show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

observa que añades como argumento de la función el evento que le pasas para poder obtener el Stage.

en las demás funciones que hacen lo mismo en la clase PruebaVentanas deberías hacerlo así.

Fijate que en la clase VentanaPrincipalController la función ventanaNew quedaría así.

```
@FXML
private void ventanaNew(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Entra boton");
    validaUsuario();

    ProgramaPrincipal.mostrarMenuAdministrador(event);

}
```

debes pasarle como argumento el evento que capturas al pulsar el botón abrir ventana.Ya solo debes preocuparte de las dimensiones que tenga las ventanas y demás, en JavaFX  hay dos formas de cambiar de vista, una es cambiar los paneles sin modificar la ventana y otra es cambiar la ventana directamente.

Contempla también la opción de cambiar de ventana en los controladores y no siempre en una Clase principal, puede ser menos engorroso a la hora de hacer lógica de ventanas.

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero reutilizar tus Stage para evitar la creación de nuevos Stages, lo que puedes hacer es re-inyectar tus FXML con FXMLLoader.

Prueba utilizando este metodo:

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane primaryWindow;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
             Stage primaryStage = (Stage) primaryWindow.getScene().getWindow();
             primaryStage.setScene(loadView("Reservation", "reservationStyles"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   //Si deseas hacer alguna enumeracion para tus vistas o 
   //un array con las vistas que tienes creadas es mucho mas legible y facil de reutilizar.
   public static Scene loadView(String viewName, String cssFile) {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(AppController.class.getClass().getResource(viewName + ".fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(PlayListController.class.getClass()
                        .getResource(cssFile + ".css").toExternalForm());
                return scene;
   }

 }
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda. Saludos.